# How to disable Google Visualizations Tool Tips?

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

Does anyone know how to disable the tool-tip boxes that popup when a Google Visualizations' chart is clicked (Selected)?

Following the sample code at [Getting Started with Visualizations](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start), the "zoom details" feature I've developed don't override the default tool tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `setEnableTooltip(boolean)` method in [CommonOptions](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/visualization/1.0/com/google/gwt/visualization/client/CommonOptions.html). So I imagine you can set that option to false on the option object you pass in the constructor of your chart. e.g. based on [Getting Started with Visualizations](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=gwt-google-apis&s=gwt-google-apis&t=VisualizationGettingStarted)

```
...
PieChart pie = new PieChart(createTable(), createOptions());
...
private Options createOptions() {
  Options options = Options.create();
...
  options.setEnableTooltip(false);
  return options;
}
...
```